# 'FATAL: database "demodb" does not exist' When trying to connect spring boot application to postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to connect my spring boot application to my postgresql database (with docker) with the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "demodb" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2578) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2690) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:156) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:255) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:80) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:438) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:149) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.LearnSpring.LearnSpringApplication.main(LearnSpringApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

2020-04-01 14:34:38.168  WARN 17616 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: database "demodb" does not exist
```

Before, i had an issue, where i got a Fatal error that my Password was wrong. I made it made it go away (not sure if that leaded to this problem) by changing the "pg_hba.conf" from:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

to:

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

Then i have restarted the server with:

```
docker restart container-name
```

OS: Windows 10

my "application.yml" in my springboot application is:

```
app:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demodb
    username: postgres
    password: password
    pool-size: 30
```

How do i fix this issue?

Comment: Show us how you're starting the postgresql database, especially the port mapping option

Comment: You must create `demodb` database manually in Postgres at first.

Comment: See this site: https://medium.com/better-programming/connect-from-local-machine-to-postgresql-docker-container-f785f00461a7

Comment: @Kartoch What i did was in the docker terminal, i typed (after each line i pressed return):

docker run --name postgres-spring -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:alpine

docker exec -it dockerID bin/bash

psql -U postgres

CREATE DATABASE demodb;

Comment: @Nasir i tried using pgAdmin 4, but i couldn't connect to server: could not connect to server.  Dialog box asking me for the password: "Please enter the password for the user 'postgres' to connect the server - "PostgreSQL 10" ".  But After i enterted the password, i got this error message: "Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? "

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770884/how-to-connect-to-postgres-database-on-docker-in-windows-10-using-sqlalchemy

Comment: @Nasir I tried that just now. I used the IP address that the docker terminal gave me.Now i have a different error which is:  " psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "192.168.x.x" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"  I also tried using Windows cmd using "psql -h 192.168.x.x -p 5432 -U postgres" and i got the exact same error.

Comment: I have managed to solve this issue. I think i still don't have the hang of docker yet. What i did was i stopped and removed the old container, created a new one and tried to use the IP address from the Docker Quick start terminal  instead of "local host".  The one thing that i don't understand is that if i close the terminal and reopen it, i cannot access it anymore, but the containers still exist. When i use "docker ps", it won't show. Any idea why that is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue, just simply stop the Postgres app if you’ve downloaded it before, then the problem will be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Postgres database is installed locally on your machine.
If so, then uninstalling it should do the work.
`localhost:5432` is captured by your local database and demodb does not exist there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have been following Amigos Code Tutorial!!
If so, you are are running postgres on docker, so it would be advised to stop the postgres(locally installed on pc) and restart the spring application.You are connecting to the container right!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your modification of "pg_hba.conf" file led to that error.

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

just configured PostgreSQL to accept all incoming connections.
I guess the reason is that your local computer has a PostgreSQL running which takes the port 5432.  I suggest changing the port number to another free one, for example, 5433 in the command that mirashgoku posted for you:

```
docker run --name postgres-spring -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -p **5433**:5432
```

Meanwhile, please change the port number in your "application.yml":

```
jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:**5433**/demodb
```